# Wildfly altera o GMT

Tags: java, android

Boa tarde.
Pessoal estou com  um  problema em uma Api back-end rodando em um servidor Wildfly ,tenho um app mobile que faz um  post nessa api em uma variável do tipo java.util.Date, quando faço o post no servidor ele adiciona 2 hrs a mais, e quando faço o mesmo teste no estado de SP, não ocorre essa alteração. Alguém sabe se tem alguma configuração que tem de ser feita no servidor ou na Api.

Comment: Sem o codigo é dificil afirmar, mas provavelmente é relacionado a diferença de timezones entre SP e o servidor

Comment: Era isso mesmo o problema estava no timezone. Obrigado

Comment: Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.